# Why am I getting the error "Exception thrown: write access violation. p was nullptr.?

Tags: c

I am coding a deck and when I try to run it to assign values to each node and then print it, I get this error when going through the `addcard` method:

```
exception thrown: write access violation. p was nullptr.
```

Why is it not okay to work with `NULL`?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define RAND_MAX 51

typedef struct card_s {
    char suit;
    int face;
    struct card_s *next, *previous;
} card;

void addcard(card *p, card **hl, card **hr, int i, char c) {
    card *temp;
    temp = (card *)malloc(sizeof(card)); 
    temp->face = i;
    temp->suit = c;
    if (*hl == NULL) {
        temp->previous = NULL;
        temp->next = NULL;
        *hl = temp;
        *hr = temp;
    } else if (p == NULL) {
        temp->previous = p;
        temp->next = NULL;
        p->next = temp;
        *hr = temp;
    } else {
        temp->next = p->next;
        temp->previous = p;
        p->next = temp;
        temp->next->previous = temp;
    }
}

void delectecard(card *p, card **hl, card **hr) {
    if (p == *hl) {
        *hl = p->next;
    } else {
        p->previous->next = p->next;
    }
    if (p == *hr) {
        *hr = p->previous;
    } else {
        p->next->previous = p->previous;
    }
    free(p);
}

void createdeck(card *p, card **hl, card **hr) {
    int i = 1;
    int j;
    while (i <= 13) {
        j = 1;
        while (j <= 4) {
            if (j == 1)
                addcard(p, hl, hr, i, 'S');
            if (j == 2)
                addcard(p, hl, hr, i, 'H');
            if (j == 3)
                addcard(p, hl, hr, i, 'D');
            if (j == 4)
                addcard(p, hl, hr, i, 'C');
        }
    }
}

void printdeck(card *currentNode) {
    while (currentNode != NULL) {
        printf("Face: %d, Suit: %c\n", currentNode->face, currentNode->suit);
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    card *headl = NULL, *headr = NULL;
    createdeck(headr, &headl, &headr);
    printdeck(headl);
}
```

Comment: If you signed up for a C++ class it's only fair to tell you that you're not learning C++. Looks like you might be using a C++ compiler, but you're learning C.

Comment: `#define RAND_MAX 51` is not such a good idea. The standard library already contains  a `RAND_MAX` macro. Weirdness could result. The `while (j <= 4)` depends on `j` for the exit condition, but `j` is never changed.

Comment: Gavin, I recommend drawing some pictures to help you visualize the problem. Draw the `cards` and how they need to be linked together to produce a stable list. Draw all the steps you need to go through to add an item to the list when it is empty, when it has one `card`, and for good measure when it has five `cards` to make sure you don't think your way into a freaky little bug where you can only ever add one `card`. Use the pictures to help you establish the logic you need in order to write the code. You'll probably find that `p` doesn't do anything and can be junked.

Answer (score 1):

In your function addcard(); You check to see if p is NULL:

```
else if (p == NULL) {
    temp->previous = p;
    temp->next = NULL;
    p->next = temp;
    *hr = temp;
```

Then, you try and access the NULL p in the line:

```
 p->next = temp;
```

How can you access something which doesn't exist! That is where the null pointer exception error is coming from.

Maybe you want to initialize p to be a new card_s struct like you did with temp. Using calloc will initialize both the next and previous pointers to NULL.

```
p = calloc(1, sizeof(card));
```

You are stuck in an infinite loop after this, specifically in your createdeck function. The reason is that you never increment or decrement either j or i so the loop never breaks.

```
while (i <= 13) {

    j = 1;
    while (j <= 4) {
        if (j == 1)
            addcard(p, hl, hr, i, 'S');
        if (j == 2)
            addcard(p, hl, hr, i, 'H');
        if (j == 3)
            addcard(p, hl, hr, i, 'D');
        if (j == 4)
            addcard(p, hl, hr, i, 'C');
    }
}
```

Comment: `p` is passed by value. The asker can set it to whatever they want and the most that'll happen is a memory leak when the function exits. `p` needs to be rethought from the bottom up.